# Question about react-bootstrap-typehead library

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I want to get all properties of a particular input option. For an example lets think my options list is

```
const options = [
        { id: 1, state: 'AL' },
        { id: 2, state: 'AK' },
        { id: 3, state: 'AZ' },
        { id: 4, state: 'AR' },
        { id: 5, state: 'CA' }
      ]

<AsyncTypeahead
    ref={textBoxRef}
        options={options}
/>
```

By using ref I can access input node of typehead as `ref.current.getInput()`. Ans also I can take the selected value by using  `ref.current.getInput().value`.

But how can I take the id attribute in the options list. So if there is any functionality take all the attributes of a particular selected options please mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using onChange prop. It has mentioned in the documentation.

Link: [enter link description here](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/main/docs/Usage.md#controlled-recommended)

I can access all the attributes of a selected option by using selected parameter in the onChange prop

```
onChange={(selected)=>{
   console.log(selected)                
}}
```